# Text Zoom in putty emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I'm currently using Emacs 23.1 on a remote server through putty. I would like to be able to zoom out (so I can view all my code when needed). I've tried several methods and none of them have worked.

Text-scale-decrease and text-scale-increase give no errors but don't change the text size

The zoom-frm plugin tells me that "symbol's function definition is void: query-fontset" when I attempt to use any of its methods (all dependencies listed are installed)

The doremi-frm plugin either gives no errors and does nothing, or complains about face-remap (depending on what function is used)

I'm wondering at this point if zoom is possible within putty, and if so how do I get it to work properly.

P.S. Opening a remote X11 session with the Emacs GUI is not an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to config `putty` instead.

Open putty, then `right click > Change Settings > Window > Fonts` on the left panel to change font size.

Comment: That might work but I'm looking for more of an on-the-fly incremental change. i.e. I don't want to be zoomed out all the time, only when I want to look at large sections of code at once. Also, How do I "click" on window when I am in a putty session with the terminal version of emacs.

Answer (score 0):

1. What Emacs are you using? You say Emacs 23.1, but that has `query-fontset' (as do also older and more recent Emacs versions, from GNU Emacs 20 to the latest GNU Emacs 24 dev build).
2. Likewise, GNU Emacs 23.1 has `face-remap' and all of its relatives,`face-remap-*'.
3. I can't answer the putty questions, but can you check in some other way whether Emacs at the remote end actually zooms OK using any of the methods you describe?  IOW, try to remove putty from the equation, to see what happens.

Comment: I've managed to fix/workaround the issue by moving from putty to a cygwin ssh session (cygwin has dynamic text resizing which changes font size and re-renders terminal ). If I get the chance I can try some of those other methods in emacs via cygwin. We recently moved to a new server that has a newer version of emacs (not positive of version number, haven't checked yet). I'll see if any of those methods work in the new version and report back for anyone with similar issues when I get the chance.